# creating my first simple geometry shader

Tags: opengl, shader

I'm trying to create the simplest geometry shader ever.

I have a working vertex and fragment shaders and I'm drawing triangles with

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Vertex Shader:

```
// vertex shader
#version 120
attribute vec3 in_position;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main() {
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(in_position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
// fragment shader
#version 120

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

Geometry Shader

```
//geometry shader
#version 120
#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4: enable

void main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < gl_VerticesIn; i++) {
        gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[i];
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

my compile method which compiles all my shaders works without returning any gl_error

This is my attach and link method and this is where I get when I try to specify the output values for my shader

```
void attached_and_link_shaders() {
    glAttachShader(programid, shaderV);
    glAttachShader(programid, shaderG);
    glAttachShader(programid, shaderF);

    glProgramParameteriEXT(programid, GL_GEOMETRY_INPUT_TYPE_EXT, GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl_error("EXT INPUT TYPE");

    // error here
    glProgramParameteriEXT(programid, GL_GEOMETRY_OUTPUT_TYPE_EXT, GL_TRIANGLES);
    gl_error("EXT OUTPUT TYPE"); // OUTPUT TYPE 1281 invalid value

    glProgramParameteriEXT(programid, GL_GEOMETRY_VERTICES_OUT_EXT, 3);
    gl_error("EXT VERTICES OUT");

    glLinkProgram(programid);
}
```

Where could my problem be? any references to good geometry shader tutorials for version 120 would be helpful,

Edit my out vertices were in correct, the solution is using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP
my problem is solved and I feel like crying

Thanks

Comment: The geometry shader should have informations on the in- and ouput. For simple triangle pass through: `layout(triangles) in; layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;`

Comment: I don't think I can use layout with version 120 :(

Comment: Did you test that? ES 1.2 is based on Opengl 1.5 and should include layout qualifiers.

Comment: @nevermind: Prior to layout qualifiers, you had to set that stuff using program parameters. The `GL_EXT_geometry_shader4` extension spec. goes over this. But if you're just starting out with geometry shaders, why not use the core version? You're going to find more tutorials and such that cover that than this old extension.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman do you have a tutorial on how to set these correctly, my error is currently at that step